# How to create and start a TCP server through UnitTesting using [ClassInitialize]?

Tags: c#, sockets, unit-testing, tcp, visual-studio-2015

What I am doing is a TCP client-to-server exerise in the form of a calculation program. The "client" is entering a math command and two numbers, and the server performs the calculation for him and returns a result (exp. Add 5 5 ; Result is 10). To do this the server needs to be started and running and *then* the client should be trying to connect. The server and the client are two different console applications.

Now, to test the program I move the client related code into a test project and run the server from its normal project. This works and the tests pass:

```
 [TestClass]
 public class UnitTest1
 {
    static TcpClient connectionSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 5678);
    static Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
    static StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    static StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodAdd()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Add 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 10);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodSubstract()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Substract 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodMultiply()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Multiply 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 25);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodDivide()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Divide 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodPercent()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Percent 100 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 5);
        KillConnection();
    }

    private static void KillConnection()
    {
        connectionSocket.Close();
        ns.Close();
    }

    private static int GetResponce(string request)
    {
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.WriteLine(request);
        string message = sr.ReadLine();
        return Convert.ToInt32(message);
    }
}
```

The next step I should perform is making the unit-test self-sufficient, by coding it to create, start and stop the server on its own through [ClassInitialize] (or what other way cold I use?).

How should I do this?

***THIS DOES NOT WORK***, My attempt was to move the server code in the test class and then run the method that starts it with [ClassInitialize]:

```
        class TcpChatServerA
{
    public void StartServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(5678);
        //Console.WriteLine("Server is started.");
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient connectionSocket = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        ChatService service = new ChatService(connectionSocket);
        service.ServiceHandler();
        listener.Stop();
    }
}

class ChatService
{
    private TcpClient connectionSocket;
    public ChatService(TcpClient connectonSocketEntry)
    {
        connectionSocket = connectonSocketEntry;
    }
    public void ServiceHandler()
    {

        //Console.WriteLine("Server is activated");
        Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        string message = sr.ReadLine();
        char[] deliminerChars = { ' ', ',', '.', '/', ':', ';' };
        string[] equationMembers = new string[5];
        int result = 0;
        while (message != null)
        {
            equationMembers = message.Split(deliminerChars);
            switch (equationMembers[0])
            {
                case "Add":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Substract":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) - Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Multiply":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) * Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Divide":
                    if (equationMembers[1] == "0")
                    {
                        message = "You attempt to divide by zero please try again";
                    }
                    else if (equationMembers[2] == "0")
                    {
                        message = "You attempt to divide by zero please try again";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[1]) / Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[2]));
                        ;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Percent":
                    message = Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[2])) / 100) * Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[1]));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid equation command. Valid commands are " +
                                      "'Add', 'Substract', 'Multiply', 'Divide', Percent (y% (from) x)");
                    break;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
            sw.WriteLine(message);
            message = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        ns.Close();
        connectionSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

And starting the server:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpChatServerA server = new TcpChatServerA();
        server.StartServer();
    }

    //the rest is the test class as seen in the first code block

    //static TcpClient connectionSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 5678);
    //static Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
    //static StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    //static StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

    //[TestMethod]
    //public void TestMethodAdd()
    //{
        //int response = GetResponce("Add 5 5");
        //Assert.AreEqual(response, 10);
    //}
    //...
```

Thus the whole code would be:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
namespace MathTCPServerTest
{
class TcpChatServerA
{
    public void StartServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(5678);
        //Console.WriteLine("Server is started.");
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient connectionSocket = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        ChatService service = new ChatService(connectionSocket);
        service.ServiceHandler();
        listener.Stop();
    }
}

class ChatService
{
    private TcpClient connectionSocket;
    public ChatService(TcpClient connectonSocketEntry)
    {
        connectionSocket = connectonSocketEntry;
    }
    public void ServiceHandler()
    {

        //Console.WriteLine("Server is activated");
        Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        string message = sr.ReadLine();
        char[] deliminerChars = { ' ', ',', '.', '/', ':', ';' };
        string[] equationMembers = new string[5];
        int result = 0;
        while (message != null)
        {
            equationMembers = message.Split(deliminerChars);
            switch (equationMembers[0])
            {
                case "Add":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Substract":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) - Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Multiply":
                    message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[1]) * Convert.ToInt32(equationMembers[2]));
                    break;
                case "Divide":
                    if (equationMembers[1] == "0")
                    {
                        message = "You attempt to divide by zero please try again";
                    }
                    else if (equationMembers[2] == "0")
                    {
                        message = "You attempt to divide by zero please try again";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[1]) / Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[2]));
                        ;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Percent":
                    message = Convert.ToString(((Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[2])) / 100) * Convert.ToDecimal(equationMembers[1]));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid equation command. Valid commands are " +
                                      "'Add', 'Substract', 'Multiply', 'Divide', Percent (y% (from) x)");
                    break;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
            sw.WriteLine(message);
            message = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        ns.Close();
        connectionSocket.Close();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpChatServerA server = new TcpChatServerA();
        server.StartServer();
    }

    static TcpClient connectionSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 5678);
    static Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
    static StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    static StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodAdd()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Add 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 10);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodSubstract()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Substract 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodMultiply()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Multiply 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 25);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodDivide()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Divide 5 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodPercent()
    {
        int response = GetResponce("Percent 100 5");
        Assert.AreEqual(response, 5);
        KillConnection();
    }

    private static void KillConnection()
    {
        connectionSocket.Close();
        ns.Close();
    }

    private static int GetResponce(string request)
    {
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.WriteLine(request);
        string message = sr.ReadLine();
        return Convert.ToInt32(message);
    }
}
}
```

This presents me with the error of:

Test Name:  TestMethodPercent
Test FullName:  MathTCPServerTest.UnitTest1.TestMethodPercent
Test Source:    *My directories*\MathTCPServerTest\UnitTest1.cs : line 132
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Result StackTrace:
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at MathTCPServerTest.UnitTest1..cctor() in *My Directories*\MathTCPServerTest\UnitTest1.cs:line 97
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at MathTCPServerTest.UnitTest1..ctor()
Result Message: Unable to create instance of class MathTCPServerTest.UnitTest1. Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathTCPServerTest.UnitTest1' threw an exception. --->   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5678.

I'm not understanding [ClassInitialize] correctly, am I?

**PS**: I am open to suggestions for both code improvement and how to better present my problems and quesitons in stackoverflow.

Comment: as to the suggestions: the way you stuffed several questions into one SO question lowers the chances of getting an answer. For suggestion on code improvement have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Another problem is that the question itself is not consistent: In the title, you require an answer to be based on `ClassInitialize` but later you are asking `or what other way cold I use?` This lowers the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Fair enough about the code improvement. The "second" question after ClassInitialize was my way of saying "If I'm doing it too wrong, how should I?", but I guess I phrased it in a dubious way.

Comment: And now a suggestion for code improvement: the server side can be implemented simpler then what you showed by employing a framework to handle the low level stuff. You can see an example how it could be implemented at https://gist.github.com/Arcitectus/3a56dae67fc7ab85e787

Comment: While I *think* I understand how that would simplify the process, the code itself is way over my head for the moment. Thanks for the effort nonetheless. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to create and start and dispose of a TCP server for each unit test

> The next step I should perform is making the unit-test
>   self-sufficient, by coding it to create, start and stop the server on
>   its own through [ClassInitialize] (or what other way cold I use?).
>
> How should I do this?

Since you want to start and stop per unit test and have several of them in one `[TestClass]`, `[ClassInitialize]` is of no use here.
One way to do this is to wrap your testing environment in a class implementing [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use it in a `using` block in a unit test.
The following code does this and answers the question of *How to create and start and dispose of a TCP server **for each unit test***:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Net;

namespace TCPServerTest
{
    class TestEnvironment : IDisposable
    {
        TcpListener TcpServer;

        readonly public int TcpServerAddress;

        public TestEnvironment(int TcpServerAddress = 5678)
        {
            this.TcpServerAddress = TcpServerAddress;

            TcpServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, TcpServerAddress);

            TcpServer.Start();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            TcpServer.Stop();
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestContainer
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestUsingTcpServer()
        {
            using (var TestEnvironment = new TestEnvironment())
            {
                var TcpClient = new TcpClient();

                TcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, TestEnvironment.TcpServerAddress);

                Assert.IsTrue(TcpClient.Connected, "TcpClient.Connected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### on [ClassInitialize]

> I'm not understanding [ClassInitialize] correctly, am I?

That seems probable given the code you posted. This is what the framework says about a method which has a `[ClassInitialize]` attribute attached:

> The method must be static, public, does not return a value
>   and should take a single parameter of type TestContext.

But even if you used the signature required for `[ClassInitialize]` you would still get the same exception because your static field initializer (where the exception stems from) is executed earlier.

Comment: I assume creating, starting and stopping a server for **each test** is the right way of doing it, instead of having a **single server running throughout the test** and closing when they are finished?

Comment: @Derptastic: creating, starting and stopping a server for each test is only *one* right way when ignoring that you made it a requirement (`making the unit-test self-sufficient, by coding it to create, start and stop the server on its own`). This way has its pros and cons. A pro being that if you would use one server for multiple tests, the tests could affect each other via state aggregated on the server.

Comment: I'm a little embaressed to ask this, but is it possible to give me an exmaple of how to combine your solution with mine. I tried and could not get it running. =(

Comment: @Derptastic: you can load that combination with your code from http://pastebin.com/9iwjvnnN (the test passes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have understood the [ClassInitialize] well enough but the problem is that you got a Type Initialization Exception and this one is usually thrown when a static field of the class can't be initialized. I don't think that you can make TcpClient and Stream static - they should be initialized somewhere inside a method. I would suggest removing all the static fields in UnitTest1 class and just move them to the GetResponse method like this:

```
private static int GetResponce(string request)
{
    TcpClient connectionSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 5678);
    Stream ns = connectionSocket.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    sw.WriteLine(request);
    string message = sr.ReadLine();
    return Convert.ToInt32(message);
}
```

This one should work well :)

Comment: This one produces the *same* error. I'd like to point out the while the server is on a separate project, the static fields do **work**, the tests connect and pass, but it's after the server is supposed to run inside the project that I get refused `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...`.